# How Can I Retrieve Command Line Arguments Injected Into IConfigurationBuilder?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration, command-line-arguments

I'd like to pass `args` (which are of type `string[]`) to my `IConfigurationBuilder` available via the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` NuGet package, and then retrieve it later on. I notice that `IConfigurationBuilder` has `AddCommandLine`, but I'm not sure where these `args` end up, or how I can access them. Ideally I'd like them dependency injected into a constructor of a class I later defined in `ConfigureServices`, as shown below (`SomeHostedService`).

For example, I have the following piece of code.

```cs
    public static class HostBuilder
    {
        public static IHost BuildHostContext(string[] args) => 
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
            {
                c.AddCommandLine(args); // Where can I access args later on?
            }).ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                // Add some services...
                services.AddHostedService<SomeHostedService>(); 
                // Would ideally like args dependency injected in SomeHostedService
            }).Build();
    }
```

1. How can I dependency inject these `args` into the constructor of `SomeHostedService`.
2. If I wanted to explicitly gain access to them, how can I retrieve them? Are they attached to the `IServiceCollection` somewhere?

**EDIT**: Constructor of `SomeHostedService` should take in a `string[]` which corresponds to `args` passed into the application.

```cs
public class SomeHostedService
{
   public SomeHostedService(string[] files)
   {
      _files = files;
   }

   public void ReadFiles()
   {
      foreach (var file in _files)
         DoSomething(file);
   }
   
   private void DoSomething(string filename)
   {
       // Do something...
   }

   private readonly string[] _files;
}
```

My entry point to the application would look as such (C# 9):

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

using var host = HostBuilder.BuildHostContext(args);
using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
await host.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: [AddCommandLine Source code here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine/CommandLineConfigurationExtensions.cs,66)

Comment: Give an example of what `SomeHostedService` needs the `args` for. You are most likely asking us for the wrong thing. `AddCommandLine` stores the args as a source for mapping access to it via `IConfiguration`

Comment: @Nkosi Done. Please see my example of how I'd like to consume `string[] args`

Comment: And what would the command line look like to start this program?

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#command-line-1

Comment: @Nkosi Added Program.cs entry-point. I can retrieve command line arguments by indexing into the IConfiguration object as shown in your documentation. I know that part. But I want to retrieve all values stored in `args` without needing to know the keys. Looks like this is not possible (?)

Comment: You could always store the args value in a custom type and add it to the container.

Comment: @Nkosi I think I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

To access the Configuration Providers, include the IConfiguration in your constructor for any of your Dependency Injection served classes.

```
public class MyClass:IMyClass{
  private IConfiguration _configuration;
  public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration){
    _configuration=configuration;
  }
}
```

To bind your arguments to a model, see this article on Microsoft Learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/model-binding